# Getting rid of one of the second keyboard dropdown suggestion list

Tags: keyboard, gboard

I just got the google Pixel 4a 5g. See the screenshot: there are 2 suggestions lists: the horizontal one just above the keyboard (where it says "GIF") and this black dropdown. I find it pretty ugly and in the way of the other suggestion list, is there a way to deactivate that dropdown?

[image]

Comment: From settings go to text correction and disable "suggestion strip"

Answer (score 0):

using help from @beeshyams, it was under System -> Language > Tools -> disable spelling check

The suggestion strip (under System -> keyboards) is the horizontal bar that I wanted to keep.